# How do you create a rough time row in sqlite?

Tags: database-design, sqlite, intervals

I'm trying to create a time row that indicates the duration of a drive.  An example would be: From point A to point B it takes about 20-25 minutes.  How should I go about creating that?  Does it qualify as an interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have a native data type for timestamps or even time intervals; it uses [strings or numbers that must be interpreted appropriately](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

I would suggest that you store the duration as the number of seconds.

In SQL, one interval specifies the *exact* difference between two points in time, for example, "20 minutes".
If you want to express an interval of intervals (such as "20-25 minutes"), you have to use two fields, e.g., `duration_min` and `duration_max`.

Comment: Sounds like my initial plan, but I lost it along the way.  Thank you.

Comment: Say, can you see deleted questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262362/structure-of-tables-for-content-in-content ?  This one didn't get a lot of attention, so I deleted it for fear of down votes.  I see a lot of similar questions, though.

Comment: I basically have a varchar(255) content that's loaded into random locations in various longtext contents.  I'm not sure if it's possible to describe content type a is within content type b's mth and nth entry, but I sure am curious.  If it isn't possible to show that relationship, I obviously just need to handle with some kind of regex pattern, or ignore half of the relationship and make the varchar content a permanent part of the longtext content.

Comment: That description is incomprehensible. What's a "content type"? What's an entry? What are `m` and `n`? (And don't write that in a comment, just ask a new question.)

Comment: put it in a question, as you have suggested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280800/data-within-data-in-sqlite

Comment: As expected, it was downvoted.  That's why I didn't want to ask the question.  It's a waste of reputation to ask something that you know people won't be able to answer.  People on this site look at a challenging question like a kick in the nuts.  I have to deal with the fallout.